Dark screen areas become grey around the cursor
On my Windows computer, I have turned off adaptive screen brightness in the settings. But still, whenever my cursor is over a dark area of the screen, it becomes grey. So the brightness is still clearly adapting. This gives me a headache and it is bad for watching movies and playing games.
There are many suggestions for how to fix this on the internet. I think most of them are from at least 4 years ago, however, and not relevant for me.

I have changed the Windows settings and Intel graphics settings with no success. There were no relevant Nvidia settings that I could change.

I looked in the BIOS settings, but there was no option for screen brightness that I could see.

Some have suggested certain command lines or changing the registry. The command lines didn't work, and in the registry I don't even have the folder that they suggest to make changes in.


I have an Asus laptop with an Intel processor and an Nvidia graphics card.
This should be a very simple problem with a very simple solution. Does anyone know what I can do?

You have tried to disable it?

The only place that allows me to disable it is in windows settings. I disable it, but it is applied the same.

I wonder if the display has local dimming. What's the make and model? If it has and it's an Asus laptop, maybe this Reddit page has a solution: PSA About Mini-LED Screens: There is a Game-Changing Feature Only Asus Has.

If you have disabled it. Then what your experiencing isn’t caused by Adaptive Screen Brightness

I found the answer to my problems thanks to Andrew Morton in the comments above. In Armoury Crate, there is an option in System Configuration called 'one zone'/'multi zone'. It needs to be in one zone.
Now everything works perfectly!

It's usual here to ask someone who gave a comment which fixed the problem to write it as an answer, but never mind :) Perhaps you could expand your answer to include some information about what the one zone/multi zone setting is for so that it is more likely to be found by internet search engines and so have a good chance of helping more people. (Don't copy-and-paste though, please, as that could be seen as plagiarism.)

Apparently there is an alternative to Armory Crate which can also change that setting: G-Helper - Lightweight control tool for Asus laptops. (I have no connection to it.)
